# Loading models with ArCore in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, arcore

I'm struggling to follow the examples to load in my own model with ArCore. I found the following code:

```java
ModelRenderable.builder()
    // To load as an asset from the 'assets' folder ('src/main/assets/andy.sfb'):
    .setSource(this, Uri.parse("andy.sfb"))

    // Instead, load as a resource from the 'res/raw' folder ('src/main/res/raw/andy.sfb'):
    //.setSource(this, R.raw.andy)

    .build()
    .thenAccept(renderable -> andyRenderable = renderable)
    .exceptionally(
        throwable -> {
          Log.e(TAG, "Unable to load Renderable.", throwable);
          return null;
    });
```

However I can't find the class ModelRenderable anywhere and how to import it. Also the example app I'm building app from loads models like this:

```java
virtualObject.createOnGlThread(/*context=*/ this, "models/andy.obj", "models/andy.png");
virtualObject.setMaterialProperties(0.0f, 2.0f, 0.5f, 6.0f);
```

But my model has no png files, just obj and mtl. The automatic sceneform also created a sfa and sfb file.
Which one is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For reference here is the official documentation about initiating a model: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform#renderables

The `ModelRenderable` is part of the 
`com.google.ar.sceneform:core`
library, you could add it by adding this dependency to your app level `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform:core:1.13.0'
```

Make sure every other arcore / sceneform dependency is on the same version, in this case 1.13.0 .

The `sfa` meaning is SceneFormAsset, it represents your your model details in a humanly readable form and wouldn't be part of your application (it should be in the samplefolder which is on the same hierarchy level as your src folder). The `sfb` however is SceneFormBinary, this binary is generated from the sfa descriptor every time you modify something in the sfa and build the project. The sfb file should be in your assets folder in your project. For model loading, you should use the `sfb` file:

```
ModelRenderable.builder()
        .setSource(context, Uri.parse("house.sfb"))
```

About your sample code: if you aren't familiar with OpenGL I don't recommend you to follow that sample, better to look for SceneForm, here is a sample app: https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/solarsystem

Comment: I think the sample code makes a mistake by assuming all dev's want to load the model from /res/raw. They should have considered the traditional happy path that is: download a file and then use it.